# Source for multiple names

Tags: names, talmud-gemara, tanach

What is the source of giving multiple names?

Who is the earliest person who had two given names? Any Tannah Amorah or Rishon?

Note that I am aware that people in tanach (Moshe Avraham etc.) as well as Tannaim were referred to by multiple names. My question is only regarding names given by birth.

Comment: There's Rav Yaakov Yisrael student of Rabbenu Tam http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%AA%D7%9D#.D7.AA.D7.9C.D7.9E.D7.99.D7.93.D7.99.D7.95